# How to add body content to a file line by line

Tags: routes, apache-camel

I have a question to camel routes.
I try to write the body to a file. It's working but I have always just the last body content in my file.
What I want is to add the body content line by line in one file. I should be a small "logfile" for me to check something.

How can I do it? I don't find the right option for this.

This is my current route:

```
        <route>
            <from uri="direct:write2file" />
            <setBody>
                <simple>${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ${body}</simple>
            </setBody>

            <to uri="file:///tmp/permissionLogs/?fileName=permissionLog.txt" />
        </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried it but according to the documentation it should be

```
<to uri="file:///tmp/permissionLogs/?fileName=permissionLog.txt&amp;fileExist=Append" />
```

Comment: how can I do a line break after each entry?

Comment: Have you tried to add \n to end of you log message? Something like: <simple>${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ${body} \n</simple>

Comment: Perfect. It worked, Sergey. You are the BEST @Sergey

Comment: Thanks :) Just remember: it is stackoverflow site. If you like the answer - accept and upvote it